# Radeon Drivers R9 270X Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, radeon, ubuntu-drivers

Do I need drivers for my graphic card Radeon R9 270X? If yes how can I install them?

Comment: use "additional drivers" (take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers) Topic)

Answer (score 3):

Open the *Software & Updates* utility and open the *Additional drivers* tab.

If your graphics card is listed, like in the picture below, the proprietary drivers can be used, and you can install them from this screen with a single click, if you have Ubuntu already installed.

The installation will, however, not work on a live system, as video drivers are one of the few things which require a reboot. (And no, persistent pendrives don't work either, the installation will only work on a fully installed system.)

[image]

If the graphics card is not listed, then your graphics card is most likely not compatible with the proprietary AMD driver. If the default, open source driver works, stay with it.